# Screenshot with Markups does not work correctly when resizing image

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm following this [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/screenshot-markups) to make screenshots with markups
however in my application the user can resize the image before the screenshot. It works correctly when it doesn't show the markups
however when it shows the markups they appear outside the positions.

[Without resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw6wt.jpg)

[With resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itjRH.jpg)

My code is:

```
function snapshot(width, height) {
    var screenshot = new Image();
    screenshot.onload = function () {
        let markupCore = MarkupsGui.core;
        let div = document.getElementById('containerComments');
        let checked = [];
        if (div) {
            checked = Array.from(div.getElementsByTagName('input')).filter(e => e.checked);
        }

        if (checked.length === 0) {
            renderToCanvas(screenshot, width, height);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
                var selectedNode = checked[i].value;
                var markupSVG = Markups.find(m => m.ID_MARKUP === parseInt(selectedNode));
                markupCore.show();
                markupCore.loadMarkups(markupSVG.MARKUP_DATA, "layerName_" + i);
            }
            //Add markups in canvas
            markupCore.renderToCanvas(renderToCanvas(screenshot, width, height), null, true);

        }
    };
    // Get the full image
    _viewer.getScreenShot(width, height, function (blobURL) {
        screenshot.src = blobURL;
    });
}

function renderToCanvas(screenshot, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('snapshot_stor');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(screenshot, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return ctx;
}
```

Is there any way to reposition these markups?

Comment: What do you mean by "resize the image before the screenshot"? What kind of image?

Comment: A dwg converted by forge, when I use the screenshot method it has an option to set the height and width of the generated image.